# user spcific packages with gwt client side

Tags: gwt

I am a newbie at GWT and I have the following query.
I have a scenario where I am trying to develop a web interface(using GWT) for an existing application. 
In the client side class file I would like to invoke a user specific class file, i understand that this is due to the fact that i am trying to invoke classes other than the ones http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html

I would like to know how this code can be called from the client side of the ui.

Thanks and Regards,

Bhavya

Comment: What kind of application is your existing java application? Server/servlet application or a desktop application?

Comment: @Peter :it is a client/server interaction applicaiton which is currently which is reading the data from the command line currently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a source code for the class you want to use and it is using only the supported Java classes, you can simply add your specific classes to client packages. If this is a reusable code, you can create a new GWT module and inherit it in your application. You can also simply move those classes to your client packages OR add a new client folder in you `.gwt.xml` file (add one more `<source>` tag)

If your class is not compilable by GWT, then I think you need to use it through [RPC service](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html).

Comment: I have used RPC for the time being and this has helped me to move beyond the exception that I was facing thank you very much for this

Answer (score 0):

If the code is translatable into JavaScript, you could for example put your individual class files into a jar and add it to the Build Path - as you would do in a 'regular' Java Project.